# Queen ant identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology, ant

I'm planning to start an artificial ant nest and I'd like to learn something about this specific species of ant that I captured in central Colorado.

Could you tell what kind of queen is that? Is there any image reference that would help me find out? Ideally with some location search possibility.
[image]

Comment: Where was the ant collected? There are some online resources for different countries that may be useful but unless there is some information to help narrow it down, you must start with the 12,500-22,000 species found across the globe.

Comment: It was captured in Colorado. Hopefully someone with more experience than me has a pretty good guess because all the sites I have found have not been to helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The picture is unclear but this ant looks like a *Solenopsis* queen. Maybe a *Solenopsis invicta*! Sorry if I'm wrong, I've only ever kept *Camponotus* and *Lasius* queens. I hope this is helpful though

[image]

Comment: This is clearly wrong, there is a post-petiole and a petiole in Solenopsis whereas you can clearly see that there is only one on his picture.

Answer (score 0):

There is clearly only one segment between the thorax and the abdomen, which rules out the possibility that this ant is a Myrmicinae.

It looks like a queen of Formicinae, probably in the genus Camponotus.

Answer (score 0):

@lucas Adam: I think so you have captured the wrong ant (worker), because the queen's head will always be shorter than its thorax. It's probably a carpenter worker ant. Further , capturing a queen is a big task because queen ants rarely come outside. And if you capture it , the entire colony it have already created will die within 2 days or maximum by a month.